# Nashorn JSON.parse() - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - JDK8u60

Tags: java-8, nashorn

Nashron Release notes claims they fixed the JSON parser bugs, but I am still able to produce a (different) bug on new patch 8u60. This time it is OutOfMemoryError.

Refer the attached JSON [1] (it is typically a Category & Subcategory relation). When I try to invoke JSON.parse() it is failing.

[1] http://jsfiddle.net/manivannandsekaran/rfftavkz/

1. I tried to increase the heap size, didn't help, instead of getting
   the OOM Exception quickly, it delayed bit.
2. When I replace all the integer key with Alpahnumberic, the entire
   parsing time is super fast. [2]

[2] https://jsfiddle.net/manivannandsekaran/8yw3ojmu/

It is almost 4 months we waited to get the original bug fixed, now again the new path introduced a another bug (it is really frustrating, I am not sure how these bugs are get escaped from regression). Is there any workaround available? Is it possible to override default JSON parser with other well known JSON parsers (like GSON or Jackson).

Here the stack trace of failure from JJS.

```
jjs> load("catsubcat/test.js")
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.arrays.IntArrayData.toObjectArray(IntArrayData.java:138)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.arrays.IntArrayData.convertToObject(IntArrayData.java:180)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.arrays.IntArrayData.convert(IntArrayData.java:192)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.arrays.IntArrayData.set(IntArrayData.java:243)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.arrays.ArrayFilter.set(ArrayFilter.java:99)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.arrays.DeletedRangeArrayFilter.set(DeletedRangeArrayFilter.java:144)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.addArrayElement(JSONParser.java:246)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.parseObject(JSONParser.java:210)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.parseLiteral(JSONParser.java:165)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.parseObject(JSONParser.java:207)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.parseLiteral(JSONParser.java:165)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.parseObject(JSONParser.java:207)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.parseLiteral(JSONParser.java:165)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:148)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSONFunctions.parse(JSONFunctions.java:80)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJSON.parse(NativeJSON.java:105)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1880587981.invokeStatic_L3_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/1095293768.reinvoke(LambdaForm$BMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1411892748.exactInvoker(LambdaForm$MH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/22805895.linkToCallSite(LambdaForm$MH)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$5$test.:program(file:catsubcat/test.js:1)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1323165413.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/653687670.invokeExact_MT(LambdaForm$MH)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:640)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:228)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.evaluateSource(Context.java:1219)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.load(Context.java:841)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.load(Global.java:1536)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1323165413.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/1413378318.reinvoke(LambdaForm$BMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$reinvoker/40472007.dontInline(LambdaForm$reinvoker)
```

Comment: Hi,
Have you tried to set the permgen space bigger ? Soon, with AOP API, classes are created at runtime, and need to be largest as set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Comment: Didn't help. If I increase the MAX Heap size the error just get delayed. Also, I am parsing proper JSON "object", there is no "array" instance invoked. But, the exception stacktrace pointing addArrayElement.

Comment: Sorry, the PermGen space does not exist anymore un JDK 8. http://java-latte.blogspot.in/2014/03/metaspace-in-java-8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just that Nashorn switches to sparse array representation too late. I filed a bug for this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137281

Comment: Thank you very much Hannes. I think the problem is not limited to JSON.parse() itself. I am able to reproduce the same OutOfMemoryError, when I iteratively generate the integer valued property  with the pattern ("\d+")  on the script-object (as given in the problematic JSON)