# Java out of memory error when I import data from json file in Kettle

Tags: json, kettle

I try to import data from a json file in kettle,but unfortunately I encountered a java error : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

The build version of my kettle is 5.4.0.1-130 and the format of my data looks like this :

```
[{"movie_title": "Carmen (English Subtitled)"},
{"movie_title": "Sugar Valentine"},
{"movie_title": "Segovia at Los Olivos [VHS]"},
{"movie_title": "Lost Boys of Sudan [VHS]"},
{"movie_title": "The Virgin of Juarez"},
{"movie_title": "Red Dawn ('84)"},
{"movie_title": "The Complete Story Deftones"},
{"movie_title": "It Came From Somewhere Else"},
{"movie_title": "Rubi"},
{"movie_title": "Fushigi Yugi - The Mysterious Play (Vol. 1)"},
{"movie_title": "Tenchi Universe, Vol. 4"}]
```

And this is a json file with 210000+ records actually.

I try to import all the movie_titles and I chose the 'Json Input' step in kettle.

The configuration of fields looks like this :

```
Name : movie_title  
Path : [*].movie_title
Type : String
Trim type : none
Repeat : N
```

After I clicked Preview rows , an error occurs with information like

```
2015/10/25 11:45:45 - Version checker - OK
2015/10/25 15:10:23 - /Users/Chris/Desktop/exercise_2/Exercise_2_Step3.ktr : Exercise_2_Step3 - Dispatching started for transformation [/Users/Chris/Desktop/exercise_2/Exercise_2_Step3.ktr : Exercise_2_Step3]
2015/10/25 15:10:31 - Json Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : UnexpectedError: 
2015/10/25 15:10:31 - Json Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2015/10/25 15:10:31 - Json Input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2015/10/25 15:10:31 - /Users/Chris/Desktop/exercise_2/Exercise_2_Step3.ktr : Exercise_2_Step3 - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2015/10/25 15:10:31 - /Users/Chris/Desktop/exercise_2/Exercise_2_Step3.ktr : Exercise_2_Step3 - Transformation is killing the other steps!
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Preview rows has dialog where u can set number of rows to preview. If u try to preview all rows it is possible to get OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Another point is that 210 000+ it isn't much. Give to JVM more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and got the same result - OutOfMemoryError. 
I generate sample of json file to experiment.

JSON file with array, contains 300000 elements. Each element with movie_title field equal to 60 symbol.

Whole file in total takes 22MB space. 
Kettle use javascript engine in jvm to parse json becouse error thrown in class

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Parser
```

It looks like that it tries to parse and load whole json file into memory before to apply any JsonPath expressions. Result is OutOfMemoryErrror.

What actually u can do is to use JavaScript step or User Defined Java Class to load json file into memory and use Java Api to parse json.

This might help 
[Nashorn JSON.parse() - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - JDK8u60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787100/nashorn-json-parse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-jdk8u60)